# What happens to a weapon affected by enlarge person when dropped but attached with a weapon cord?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, weapons, equipment

Suppose your character has their weapon out (bow/sword/doesn't matter) and has a [weapon cord](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-and-armor-accessories#TOC-Weapon-Cord) attached. You are then [enlarged](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person)/[reduced](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reduce-person) in size. You are somehow disarmed of the weapon.

Since the weapon is still anchored to you, does it change size as per the spells, or remain the same size as it has not left you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the spell text for *enlarge* on d20pfsrd.com

> Any enlarged item that leaves an enlarged creature's possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size.

As the cord is binding the weapon to it's user, it never leaves his or her possession. Therefore it should not change size. If the cord is severed, the weapon would change size if dropped.

Comment: Although...this might have some interesting implications in other areas where your size has changed...you could extend the length of a rope for example, or any number of things.

Comment: @BaseHobo Yeah, I don't like it either. Tying a rope to an enlarged spear and affixing the rope's other end to one's arm shouldn't bypass the restrictions on ranged weapons shrinking, for instance. Unfortunately, the game's unclear enough that allowing such shenanigans with *only* weapon cords is probably reasonable.